# Querying Nested Array in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I have an object that I want to index into an Elasticsearch index. Some of the fields inside the object have a nested array of JSON objects inside them. For example:

```
"history":[
        {"color":"w","from":"g2","to":"g4","flags":"b","piece":"p","san":"g4","ts":{"$numberLong":"1586861525811"}},
        {"color":"b","from":"e7","to":"e5","flags":"b","piece":"p","san":"e5","ts":{"$numberLong":"1586861527710"}},
        {"color":"w","from":"f2","to":"f4","flags":"b","piece":"p","san":"f4","ts":{"$numberLong":"1586861531620"}},
        {"color":"b","from":"d8","to":"h4","flags":"n","piece":"q","san":"Qh4#","ts":{"$numberLong":"1586861533363"}}
        ],
```

The mapping I have used for this field is:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "history" : {
        "type" : "nested",
        "properties": {
          "color": {"type" : "keyword"},
          "from" : {"type" : "keyword"},
          "to" : {"type" : "keyword"},
          "flags" : {"type" : "keyword"},
          "san" : {"type" : "keyword"},
          "ts" : {
            "type" : "nested"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The issue I am facing is that when I put the object into the index, the mapping does not work if there is more than one object stored inside the history field. In Kibana the history field is stored as follows:

```
{
  "color": "w",
  "from": "g2",
  "to": "g4",
  "flags": "b",
  "piece": "p",
  "san": "g4",
  "ts": {
    "$numberLong": "1586861525811"
  }
},
{
  "color": "b",
  "from": "e7",
  "to": "e5",
  "flags": "b",
  "piece": "p",
  "san": "e5",
  "ts": {
    "$numberLong": "1586861527710"
  }
},
{
  "color": "w",
  "from": "f2",
  "to": "f4",
  "flags": "b",
  "piece": "p",
  "san": "f4",
  "ts": {
    "$numberLong": "1586861531620"
  }
},
{
  "color": "b",
  "from": "d8",
  "to": "h4",
  "flags": "n",
  "piece": "q",
  "san": "Qh4#",
  "ts": {
    "$numberLong": "1586861533363"
  }
}
```

The different nested fields I specified in the mapping are not populated.

Is there something wrong with my mapping? It seems to work if the history field only has one object for example:

```
"history":
        {"color":"w","from":"g2","to":"g4","flags":"b","piece":"p","san":"g4","ts":{"$numberLong":"1586861525811"}}
```

But with more than one objects, it fails to map correctly. What could be the problem?

Comment: Hi, I chacked and there is not any problem with your mapping. how to you index this data? I think your problem is in the index part

Comment: I use the console in Kibana to put the object in the index i created.